# Integrate djongo (Mongo ORM) into Django Rest Framework

Tags: mongodb, orm, django-rest-framework, djongo

Actually I am developping a POC on which we want an app which has a REST API and discuss with MongoDB in Python.

For this we found several techs, such as Django-rest-framework for the API side and djongo for the ORM side. Nevertheless, I scan lots of tutos on how to implement djongo ORM in DRF, no way there is nothing BUT apparently it's possible, can someone confirm?

My main problem is my POC does absolutely not work, indeed, in used **djongo** models in my DRF Serializers but it does not work at all, I dont understand, can someone figure it out whats going on?:

**models.py:**

```
from djongo import models


class Channel(models.Model):
    sourceId = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    usageId = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    channelId = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cabinetId = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    zoneId = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Product(models.Model):
    dateCreation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    dateUpdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Unknown product name")
    channels = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=Channel,
    )

    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from Api.models import Product
from Api.serializers import ProductSerializer


@csrf_exempt
def ProductList(aRequest):
    """

    @brief List all products, or create a new product.
    """
    if aRequest.method == 'GET':
        wProducts = Product.objects.all()
        wSerializer = ProductSerializer(wProducts, many=True)

        return JsonResponse(wSerializer.data, safe=False)

    elif aRequest.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(aRequest)
        wSerializer = ProductSerializer(data=data)

        if wSerializer.is_valid():
            wSerializer.save()

            return JsonResponse(wSerializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(wSerializer.errors, status=400)


@csrf_exempt
def ProductDetail(aRequest, pk):
    """

    @brief Retrieve, update or delete a product.
    """
    try:
        wProducts = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if aRequest.method == 'GET':
        wSerializer = ProductSerializer(wProducts)
        return JsonResponse(wSerializer.data)

    elif aRequest.method == 'PUT':
        data = JSONParser().parse(aRequest)
        wSerializer = ProductSerializer(wProducts, data=data)
        if wSerializer.is_valid():
            wSerializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(wSerializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(wSerializer.errors, status=400)

    elif aRequest.method == 'DELETE':
        Product.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from Api.models import Product, Channel


class ChannelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Channel
        fields = ('sourceId', 'usageId', 'channelId', 'cabinetId', 'zoneId')

    def create(self, validated_data):

        wChannel = Channel.objects.create(**validated_data)

        return wChannel


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    channels = ChannelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('dateCreation', 'dateUpdate', 'name', 'channels')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        wChannels = validated_data.pop("channels")

        wProduct = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for wChannel in wChannels:
            Channel.objects.create(product=wProduct, **wChannel)

        return wProduct
```

When I run my server with this POST request:

```
{
    "dateCreation": "2018-07-20 12:00:00.000",
    "dateUpdate": "2018-07-20 12:00:00.000",
    "name": "post_test_channel_1",
    "channels": [{
        "sourceId": -1,
        "usageId": 100,
        "channelId": 0,
        "cabinetId": 0,
        "zoneId": 1
    }]
}
```

I obtain that stacktrace:

```
Internal Server Error: /products/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/PocEms/Api/views.py", line 25, in ProductList
    wSerializer.save()
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/PocEms/Api/serializers.py", line 29, in create
    wProduct = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1284, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1237, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1237, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1236, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1176, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 767, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/home/soulasb/projects/POC/venv-app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/models/fields.py", line 461, in get_db_prep_value
    model=Model
ValueError: Value: None must be instance of Model: <class 'django.db.models.base.Model'>
```

Comment: Have you found a good solution to this? Running into issues here and there as well ...

Comment: Is Passing an empty embedded document an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have added an EmbeddedModelField in your model and not passing an object to this field while creating an entry to this model.
I didnt find an option to add an EmbeddedModelField with null=True option.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

It could be the ENFORCE_SCHEMA set to true in settings.py. Maybe change it to "ENFORCE_SCHEMA: false".